# Which POSIX flavor of regex does Perl use?

Tags: regex, linux, perl, find, posix

Specifically, I'm using the Linux command:

```
$ find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '<some regex>' ...
```

I just want to make sure the POSIX type I'm using is the type Perl uses, since that is by far the one I am most familiar with.

Comment: Perl has defined many extensions to the POSIX regex (i.e. it isn't POSIX at all). I don't think there is a POSIX equivalent. What specific regex features do you want to use?

Comment: The difference here is the syntax of \{ and \\) etc. The extended posix ones are the ones you need.

Comment: That's like asking what kind of motorcycle a Hummer is. They're really different things, although they perform similar functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl's regexes are more like the Posix extended ones. Basic posix regular expressions use `(` and `{` to match the actual characters, and `\(` and `\{` as special characters, but the Posix extended ones use `(` and `{` for the same meaning as in Perl and `\(` or `\{` to match the actual characters, the same as Perl. So posix-extended is what you want.

Answer (score 12):

Perl has defined its own standard for regexes. E.g., there are systems such as [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/), which stands for Perl Compatible Regular Expressions.

Comment: +1, although note that PCRE isn't completely Perl-compatible.

Comment: *The name is misleading, because PCRE is Perl-compatible only if you consider a subset of PCRE's settings and a subset of Perl's regular expression facilities.* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCRE

Comment: Fixed - & you guys could have edited that in, I wouldn't have been offended. :)

Answer (score 10):

Perl's regular expression engine is Perl's regular expression engine. `perl` defines Perl.

For details, see [perldoc perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html).

Answer (score 7):

Perl uses Perl regular expressions, not POSIX ones. You can compare the syntaxes yourself, for example in `regex(7)`.

Answer (score 6):

Per [perldoc perlhist](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhist.html), Perl 0 ("Classified.  Don't ask.") used basic regular expressions.  All versions since, starting with Perl 1.000 in December of '87, have used extended regular expressions (and extended on those...).